# Weka (jvm) changing heap size

Tags: java, weka

Sorry for asking this question coz it's already asked here n solved but the problem is it doesn't work for me I've seen many resources telling me to change the size from `java runtime events` and I changed the size as this `-Xms1024m -Xmx2048`, but I  find the same error.next i tried to change the size from `Runweka.ini` But when I run `weka` i got an error `Jvm cannot start Critical error...`

SO is there any other solution may be from the os or anywhere to change these value n get out of the problem?

here is my system info

```
win 7 64 bit 4Gb RAm
Weka 3.7.8 
java 3.7
```

both installed

```
C://program files /....
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a cell phone, unless you edit your question, rewrite it and make it understandble you will likely not receive the answer you are looking for or any answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

With `-Xmx2048` you are setting the maximum heap size to `2048` *bytes*  I suggest you try instead

```
-Xmx2g
```

or

```
-Xmx2048m
```

I wouldn't bother setting the minimum. I might save a milli-second on startup.